# Is Ubuntu usable for tablet mode on laptop?

Tags: lenovo, touchscreen, tablet

I'm thinking about buying laptop `Lenovo Yoga 9 14ITL5 Shadow Black` which has tablet mode. Does Ubuntu support that? I.e.:

- does it automatically switch to tablet mode when necessary?
- does it automatically orient screen vertically / horizontally?
- is there some app for using stylus and taking notes?

I'd like to use latest LTS, which means 20.04 version, though I could switch to newer version if it would offer better support. I tried searching online, but I have only found old replies and I guess that this may have changed in recent releases.

Comment: Have a look at this question for taking notes with stylus. https://askubuntu.com/q/1240611/124466

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for any particular model and I don't know what "Tablet Mode" is or does different to normal mode but if it's any use...

I installed ubuntu on a Asus Transformer 3 Pro T303UA (maybe 19.10 at the time, now 20.10) and without doing anything special it supported automatic screen rotation (and ability to lock rotation via top-right ubuntu menu). As well as a basic on-screen keyboard.

But touch support is very basic. You can click on things and drag windows/scroll bars but that's about it. Some apps will allow scrolling by dragging inside windows but most won't. e.g. it's just a "touch screen" Ubuntu desktop, not in any way a proper tablet.

It may be possible to custom-add things to make it more tablet-like but I use primarily for a home automation (e.g. lights/music) controller/display and it's all I need and have never looked into it further.